# Recovering files from ISO file on Ubuntu 16

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery

I'm trying to recover a damaged data CD. I followed the example

```
dd if=/dev/sr0 of=image.iso bs=2048 conv=noerror,notrunc iflag=nonblock
```

on this link http://hyperlogos.org/page/Recovering-damaged-CDs-or-DVDs-Linux

and after 10 days finally ended up with 150 Mb ISO file. The fat has been damaged so it impossible to mount.

I read it with hexdump and I can see that word and other documents are there.

I'm looking for a tool to read the iso and extract / recover files inside without mounting it as you would do with a deleted or damage partition on a HD.

Any suggestions?

Yoram

Answer (score 1):

Any archive manager could do that but you need to test the ISO archive first for problems, and try to rebuild the archive. I used 7-Zip

Comment: I've tried it but it didn't work. The iso was created with **dd** so it's more likely to be a sector image.

Comment: Have you ever tried to test your archive for checksum error? If there's any, just delete your archive since it's irrevocable.